# Nested list of dicts comprehension syntax

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a list of dicts in which one of the values is another list of dicts. I'm trying to filter by a value in the second tier list of dicts (`color` in the example below). Is the first method the correct way? Or is there an easier one or two liner? My background is in MATLAB, so I'm used to logical indexing on structure arrays.

Secondary question: Is there a better way to represent this data other than a nested list of dicts?

```
testrecord = [{'testnum':1,'testdata':[{'datanum':1,'color':'green'},{'datanum':2,'color':'blue'},{'datanum':3,'color':'green'}]},
              {'testnum':2,'testdata':[{'datanum':1,'color':'yellow'},{'datanum':2,'color':'orange'},{'datanum':3,'color':'red'}]},
              {'testnum':3,'testdata':[{'datanum':1,'color':'red'},{'datanum':2,'color':'yellow'},{'datanum':3,'color':'green'}]}]    

#Method 1:          
datamatch1 = []    
for tr in range(len(testrecord)):
    for td in range(len(testrecord[tr]['testdata'])):
        if testrecord[tr]['testdata'][td]['color']=='green':
            datamatch1.append(testrecord[tr]['testdata'][td])

#Method 2 (has an unnecessary extra list layer):          
datamatch2 = []
for tr in range(len(testrecord)):
    datamatch2.append([td for td in testrecord[tr]['testdata'] if td['color']=='green'])                  

%MATLAB alternative:
datamatch = [testrecord.testdata];
datamatch = temp(strcmp({temp.color},'green'));
```

Comment: You seem to have some mis-matched references to `datamatch1` and `datamatch2`.

Comment: @JasonMArcher, You're right. I switched the order between testing on my machine and uploading to SO. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a fairly simple list comprehension:

```
>>> [t for testrec in testrecord for t in testrec['testdata'] if t.get('color') == 'green']
[{'color': 'green', 'datanum': 1}, {'color': 'green', 'datanum': 3}, {'color': 'green', 'datanum': 3}]
```

To better understand creating a list comp like this, break it down into a nested for loop:

```
for testrec in testrecord:
    for t in testrec['testdata']:
        if t.get('color') == 'green':
            #include
            t
```

Then you get rid of end line colons, and move the returned value to the front

```
t
  for testrec in testrrecord
  for t in testrec['testdata']
  if t.get('color') == 'green')
```

Then wrap it in the list comprehension's square brackets

```
[t for testrec in testrecord for t in restrec['testdata'] if t.get('color') == 'green']
```

Comment: 'fairly simple' is in the eye of the beholder. The first time I saw list comprehension with more than one `for` my mind was blown.

Comment: The expanded explanation is very useful.

Comment: @shockburner: you are absolutely right.  Perhaps a poor choice of wording on my part.  However, once you understand the list-comps (especially with more than one iterator) this example does become pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

There's almost certainly a better way to structure your data. Seeing that "testnum" and "datanum" in this case are nothing but sequential indices, the same amount of information could be stored in a simple list of lists:

```
testlist = [['green','blue','green'],
            ['yellow','orange','red'],
            ['red','yellow','green']]
```

Tuples containing the index can easily be acquired using `enumerate()` (here converted to lists to print the contents):

```
>>> list(enumerate(testlist))
[(0, ['green', 'blue', 'green']), (1, ['yellow', 'orange', 'red']), (2, ['red', 'yellow', 'green'])]
>>> [list(enumerate(x)) for x in testlist]
[[(0, 'green'), (1, 'blue'), (2, 'green')], [(0, 'yellow'), (1, 'orange'), (2, 'red')], [(0, 'red'), (1, 'yellow'), (2, 'green')]]
```

There's no need to iterate over indices, which both your examples do using `range(len(testrecord))`. In cases where the named structure is important, it might also make sense to use classes to hold the records; at least with [slots](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) they can scale better than dictionaries.

When it comes to using nested comprehensions, I find it convenient to break them up, as you can have any newlines you wish within the brackets:

```
>>> matches = [(recno,datano,data)
...            for recno,record in enumerate(testlist)
...            for datano,data in enumerate(record)
...            if data=='green']
>>> matches
[(0, 0, 'green'), (0, 2, 'green'), (2, 2, 'green')]
```

In this case I stored the indices as the original data structure preserved the `datanum` field.

Comment: The data structure actually has more fields for each entry than the example. I just stripped out everything unnecessary in order to simplify the example set. There are multiple other fields/keys in each the testrecord and testdata dicts/structures. The line breaks in the nested comprehensions is a useful thing to know though.